# Create huge zip file with php, prevent timeout

Tags: php, timeout, zip

i want to create a big zip-file with thousands (10000+) pdf-files and upload it to a external sftp server.
Currently the process always results in a timeout (already modified the php.ini), but the zip-file gets created never-the-less, but we can never be sure if everything went well and when it is finished.
I looked around but found no satisfactory response. Is there a possibility to prevent timeouts, keep the process spinning and know when it is finished? Maybe via AJAX? =/

Thanks in advance

Comment: for long running tasks command line should be used. do you have access to that?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the client needs to be able to do this, so i cannot use the command line... =/

Answer (score 0):

For upload, you can try the ZipStream class from the PHPZip project (https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip)

```
$zip = new \ZipStream("invoices.zip");

foreach($invoices as $invoice)
{
    $pdf = new InvoicePdf($invoice);
    $zip->addFile($pdf->render(), $pdf->getFilename());
}

$zip->finalize();
exit;
```

For upload, if you have tried this (https://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/), then you can google for "jquery file upload"

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that and check if it works in my case!